# Slowness in PHP While Loop

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a question. I have a table named "Other" in MySQL. Here I keep my users. There are about 50 users. I want to attract these users to [www.example.com/users.php](http://www.example.com/users.php) on my site. I pulled users with a while loop. But every time I refresh the page I wait 10-15 seconds. How can I optimize this? I tried with LIMIT but I don't want to do it with LIMIT.

```
$query=$fdb->prepare("SELECT ID,RANK,COLOR,PREFIX,CREDITS FROM Other");
$query->execute();
while ($u=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
?>
<tr id="name">
<td><?= $u['ID']; ?></td>
<td><?= $u['RANK']; ?></td>
<td><?= $u['COLOR']; ?></td>
<td><?= $u['PREFIX']; ?></td>
<td><?= $u['CREDITS']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I can't think of any reason why a query in a table with only 50 rows would take so long.

Comment: usually you build the table once and then look with ajax if there are more and update it with javascript, maybe you should take a look it before hand, but 50 users shouldn't take 10 or 15 seconds

Comment: there is something REALLY bizarre going on, because for such a query it's just impossible to run that slow. Two possible reasons: 1. there is an unrelated code that also runs on the page, either backend or frontend. 2. The host is a real crap.

Comment: It's possible that some other process has the table locked, and this query is waiting for the lock. But that wouldn't happen every time.

Comment: Can you reproduce this without using the PHP script, by just running the query from the CLI tool?

Comment: On a local development copy, or some remote server that's on an overloaded shared database?